# In cartography, what do you call the line that separates land from water?

Tags: word-request

I am discussing cartographic conventions. For instance, "rivers should be blue" and "country borders should be black".

In such a discussion, how should I refer to a line that separates land from a large body of water?
I am looking for a single term that works for ocean, sea, lake (rivers not needed).

My attempts:

- coast
- shore
- seaside line
- seaside
- bank

Is there a more appropriate term?

[image]

Comment: You probably already saw from ctype.h's edit, but a bonus vocabulary word for you: map-drawing is known as *cartography*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Shoreline* is a more general term than *coastline*, encompassing not only oceans and seas, but lakes and large rivers as well.

Comment: I dunno. I wouldn't use *shoreline* for land that's next to the ocean: that's strictly *coastline* for me. Also, *shoreline* is a more informal term, less suited to map-making.

Comment: More informal and less suited to map-making?  Perhaps, but it appears that (at least) the NOAA has no problem using [*shoreline*](http://shoreline.noaa.gov/index.html) as a general term inclusive of coastline in the context of cartography.

Comment: Shoreline was the first word that sprung to my mind as well. Seas have shores, after all, so I'm not sure why it's been suggested that shoreline is inappropriate for coasts.

Answer (score 14):

You can use *[coastline](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coastline)* for oceans, seas, and lakes, but not for rivers. You can use *boundary/boundaries* for rivers.

Comment: I don't need rivers, so `coastline` sounds perfect indeed!

Comment: shoreline would also work.

Comment: I've never heard of lake shores being called coasts. Can you imagine a street called Lake Coast Boulevard (rather than Lake Shore Boulevard)? It sounds awkward.

Comment: @Kaz: I agree with you. _Shoreline_, snailplane's suggestion, sounds much better to me as well. My little bit of research on the Net, however, turned up _coastline_. It's quite possible that there's a difference between technical & popular usage. I often find that in biomedical & business English.

Answer (score 3):

The best word depends on the classification of the body of water:

> The boundary between land and the *ocean* is the **coastline** (or **coast**).
>
> The boundary between land and a *sea* is the **shoreline** (or **shore** or **seashore**).
>
> The boundary between land and a *lake* is the **shoreline** (or **shore**).
>
> The boundary between land and a *river* is the **riverbank** (or **bank**).

*Seaside* is a more generic term, and refers to the land or attractions that are next to the sea. For instance, a hotel next to the sea might be part of a *seaside resort*.

In the context of cartography, native speakers would normally refer to the boundary around continents as **the coast**, the boundaries of lakes and internal seas as **shores** and to refer to rivers directly (i.e. as **rivers**), rather than *riverbanks*.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I need a single term that applies to the three of ocean, sea, lake... Is `shoreline` unusable for an ocean?